# Dijkstra algorithm implemented in C++ and converted to Java

Tags: java, c++, graph, dijkstra

Please, help me with this problem:
I am trying to translate Dijkstra algorithm (implemented in C++ by a professor) to Java but it's not working.

```
int     *cost = new int[numVert],
        *frj = new int[numVert],
        *parent = new int[numVert],
         w, w0;

for (w = 0; w < numVert; w++) {
    parent[w] = -1;
    cost[w] = matrizAdj[_vertInicial][w];
    frj[w] = _vertInicial;
}

parent[_vertInicial] = _vertInicial;
cost[_vertInicial] = 0;

while (1) {
    int mincost = -1;
    for (w = 0; w < numVert; w++) {
        if (parent[w] != -1 || cost[w] == 0)
            continue; // vert ja alcancado ou nao possui aresta com vert atual.

        // se menor que mincost ou mincost == infinito
        if (mincost > cost[w] || mincost == -1)
            mincost = cost[w0 = w];
    }
    if (mincost == -1) break;
    parent[w0] = frj[w0];
    for (w = 0; w < numVert; w++)
        if (cost[w] > cost[w0] + matrizAdj[w0][w]) {
            cost[w] = cost[w0] + matrizAdj[w0][w];
            frj[w] = w0;
        }
}

for (w = 0; w < numVert; w++)
    cout << " " << parent[w];
```

The professors's version is working just fine. At the end, it will print a list of parents, where parent[w] is the parent of node w.

Output example: 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 4 0 2 0.

Well, I made this code in Java:

```
double mincost, cost[] = new double[_m.length];
int frj[], parent[], w0;

frj = new int[_m.length];
parent = new int[_m.length];

for (int w = 0; w < _m.length; w++) {
    parent[w] = -1;
    cost[w] = _m[_root][w];
    frj[w] = _root;
}

parent[_root] = _root;
cost[_root] = 0;
w0 = 0;

while (true) {
    mincost = -1;

    for (int w = 0; w < _m.length; w++) {
        if (parent[w] != -1 || cost[w] == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if (mincost > cost[w] || mincost == -1) {
            mincost = cost[w0 = w];
        }
    }

    if (mincost == -1) {
        break;
    }

    parent[w0] = frj[w0];
    for (int w = 0; w < _m.length; w++) {
        if (cost[w] > cost[w0] + _m[w0][w]) {
            cost[w] = cost[w0] + _m[w0][w];
            frj[w] = w0;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(" " + parent[i]);
}
```

Which is basically the same thing, except that my version uses double to define costs (edge weight). (the double values are pretty close to integers, so I doubt this is causing the problem).
At the end, it prints the list of parents, but the elements in the list are always the `_root` value. In another words, the condition `"if (cost[w] > cost[w0] + _m[w0][w])"` are always `false` (this is clearly wrong!).

Output example:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.
```

Did I missed some spot here? Did I wrote something wrong? I am trying to find the error in this code about one hour, but they look the same...

Thank you!

Comment: That looks pretty awful. You might be better off implementing it from scratch.

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug this code?  Posting a wall of code and saying "find the problem in it" is not at all likely to make someone want to help you.

Comment: Doubles are not quite integers; that could be causing problems. Also, where is `_m[][]` declared?

Comment: This is not even Dijkstra. It looks more like Bellman-Ford to me.

Comment: Where is your input (i.e. `_m`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your algorithm and it seems to work just fine. I used the sample graph from **[here](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/222/dijkstra.pdf)** and it returned the expected results.

Sample graph (and ajducency matrix):

```
      b       d
      O-------O
     /|\      |\             0,    2,    3, 1000, 1000, 1000
   2/ | \3    | \2           2,    0,    6,    5,    3, 1000
   /  |  \   1|  \           3,    6,    0, 1000,    1, 1000
a O   |   \   |   O z     1000,    5, 1000,    0,    1,    2
   \  |6   \  |  /        1000,    3,    1,    1,    0,    4
   3\ |     \ | /4        1000, 1000, 1000,    2,    4,    0
     \|      \|/
      O-------O
      c       d
```

Parents output:

```
0 0 0 4 2 3
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/DmX0EP)**.

Based on the above facts, there must be something wrong with your input (`_m`).

Comment: Hello! Yes, I started testing randomly created graphs and everthing went well. But _m argument is working fine.

Comment: Yes, I thought _m could be wrong too but printing graph _m shown a correct output. Then I search for a graph with integers edge weights and tried out on both languages. Both returned the same result: a list with zeros. So I realize that I was testing euclidean graphs (dijkstra's would never change the parent list, because the shortest path between two nodes is the edge between them). I'm feeling very stupid for not understand this early, so my sincerely apologizes for the bothering, guys. Thanks to every one!